# Import Uni-code formated text in CSV file using php

Tags: php, csv

I want to import some data to a .CSV file. Some of the field contents are uni-code formated. But when I save  .CSV file, it doesn't put them in orginal format. it keeps them using some special character.

For what when I import the same .CSV file to database it can't read the uni-code formated data. Anyone can help me, if have a right ans.

Regards

Faysal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this method to convert the unicode character:

```
iconv("windows-1256","UTF-8",$var);
```

(this code is for the arabic unicode)